# Decrypt Wi-Fi packet of SSID which contain colons

Tags: wifi, wireshark

I am trying to decrypt an IEEe802.11 packets on Wireshark. 
Manual showed that adding "wpa-pwd" "mypassword:myssid" will do the work but the thing is ssid contain colons and it doesn't work properly.
For example, password is "12345678" and ssid is "MyAP:12:34:56" then how can I decrypt the packets? 
I have tried 
12345678:MyAp:12:34:56 but it never worked ...

Comment: Can you try *escaping* the colon's?  e.g. `12345678:MyAp\:12\:34\:56`.  If that doesn't work, and I have reasons to suspect that it might not, then try opening the **80211_keys** file (location of file should be shown in the bottom-right corner of the *"WEP and WPA Decryption Keys"* dialog window) and manually editing the entry.

You can try replacing the `:` characters with `\x3a`, so it should read like so: `12345678:MyAp\x3a12\x3a34\x3a56`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comment and I have tried both cases but didn't work ..  I will try more various ways thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried omitting the SSID altogether?  From the code, it looks to be optional, so maybe try with just the password?